# Is it possible to mark a method with multiple attributes in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, you can mark a method with different attribute such as NS_DEPRECATED, NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED, etc.

Is it possible to mark a method with multiple attributes?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Just put them all there in a row.

```
- (id)foo NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED NS_DEPRECATED(...);
```

(Note that NS_DEPRECATED isn't really for your use. It takes params for iOS or Mac version ranges, with the intention that it indicates availability in OS revs.)